# Run with volume for files generated during docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am using Docker to run unit tests, to generate Cobertura code coverage results, and then to generate an HTML reports on this (using [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator)).  I then publish BOTH the code coverage results file and the HTML reports to VSTS DevOps.

**Here are the commands I need to run:**

```
# Generates coverage.cobertura.xml for use in the next step.
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=codecoveragereports/

# Generates HTML reports from coverage.cobertura.xml file.
dotnet reportgenerator -reports:app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:codecoveragereports -reportTypes:htmlInline
```

**And now in dockerfile:**

```
WORKDIR ./app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/

RUN dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=codecoveragereports/

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "dotnet reportgenerator -reports:codecoveragereports/*.xml -targetdir:codecoveragereports -reportTypes:htmlInline"]
```

And to build the image:

```
docker build -t myapplication.tests -f dockerfile --target tester .
```

And to run it:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/codecoveragereports:/app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports myapplication.tests:latest
```

The problem:

The results file generated on `dotnet test` does get generated (I can test this with `RUN dir`), but seems to disappear when I specify a volume (using `-v`) on `docker run`.

Is it not possible to create a volume on files which are generated in the image during `docker build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The life of your container can be very roughly represented like

`docker build`

- dot test --> codecoveragereports/

`docker run -v`

1. docker mount volume `$PWD/codecoveragereports` to `codecoveragereports`, this obscured the previous `codecoveragereports`
2. your entrypoint script

So you need to output `dot test` to a temp folder, then copy it to your mount point at runtime (in the entrypoint).

dockerfile

```
COPY init.sh /
dot test --> /temp/
ENTRYPOINT ['/bin/bash', '/init.sh']
```

init.sh

```
cp /temp /app/test/MyApplication.UnitTests/codecoveragereports
exec ["/bin/bash", "-c", "dotnet reportgenerator -reports:codecoveragereports/*.xml -targetdir:codecoveragereports -reportTypes:htmlInline"]
```

Comment: @davenewza why do you want to copy to a temp folder?